# Finding parent child relationsip between columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've a pandas dataframe with a similar structure as below. I want to find out a parent child relationship between the columns i.e `Col1` is a parent of `Col2` and `Col2` is a parent of `Col3` meaning that a value of `Col1` can have multiple values of `Col2` and the same goes for `Col2` and `Col3`. In the start I don't know what is what. So I need to figure this relationship out dynamically.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
a       b       d
a       b       d
a       b       e
a       c       e
a       c       f
a       c       f
b       c       g
b       c       g
c       c       g
c       c       g
c       c       g
c       b       g
d       c       g
d       c       h
d       b       h
```

By parent child relation, I mean Col1 value `a` has multiple Col2 values i.e `b,c` against it.

Is there some kind of formula that can be used to find this out ?

The expected output can be an array of column names as following.

```
['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
```

The first index the parent most column while the last index is the child most column.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output? For each value in Col1 the children and the same for Col2?

Comment: hi please check the edit

Comment: Why col1 is the parent most column?

Comment: `a value of Col1 can have multiple values of Col2` i.e we've multiple Col2 values against a single Col1 value. For example value `a` inside Col1 has `b,c` values in Col2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get the expected result using the following code.

```
def _row_value_changed(row: Any, col1: str, col2: str) -> int:   
    if row[col1] == row[col1 + "_shifted"] and row[col2] != row[col2 + "_shifted"]:
        return 1
    return 0

shifted_df = df.shift(periods=-1)
shifted_df.columns = [str(col) + "_shifted" for col in shifted_df.columns]
df2 = pd.concat([df, shifted_df], axis=1)[0:5000]
df2["change"] = df2.apply(
    row_value_changed, args=('Col1', 'Col2'), axis=1
)
df2["change"].sum()
```

The code does the following.

1. Creates a new dataframe`(shifted_df)` with each row shifted up.
2. Append `_shifted` to the column names to distinguish both original and shifted dataframes column names.
3. Combine the columns of the original dataframe with the new shifted one into one large dataframe`(df2)`.
4. Create a new column in `df2` called `change`. This column will be assigned a value of 1 if `Col2` value changes with respect to `Col1`.
5. Sum the change column to find out how many times `Col2` changed with respect to `Col1`.

If we call the following line again with the parameters switched.

```
df2["change"] = df2.apply(
    row_value_changed, args=('Col2', 'Col1'), axis=1
)
```

Than we can calculate how many times `Col1` changed with respect to `Col2`. Which can help us compare and find which column changed with respect to the other.